# Accessing Children in LabelFrames using Tkinter and Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am working with `tkinter` and have set up a bare bones application of my project. My objective is to retrieve a value from `tk.Entry()` which lies within a `tk.LabelFrame()` (in this code referenced by the `groupbox` variable). The button finds the `groupbox`, and the code passes the compiler, too. I guess my question is: *How do I access Widgets and their values in a LabelFrame?*

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tkinter as tk


class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master.title("Application Title")

        # Introduce LabelFrame
        self.groupbox = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Parameters")
        self.groupbox.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

        # Test Label & Entry Widget
        label = tk.Label(self.groupbox, text="label=")
        label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="W")
        entry = tk.Entry(self.groupbox)
        entry.insert(0, default_value)
        entry.grid(row = 0, column=1)

        # Compile Button
        button = tk.Button(self.groupbox, text="Compile", command=self.compile)
        button.grid(row=1, column=1)

    # Retrieve first Value (second Widget) from LabelFrame
    def compile(self):
        print(self.groupbox.entry.get(1))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    figure = Application()
    figure.pack()
    figure.mainloop()
```

I am doing this because I want to perform some calculations based on the `tk.Entry()` values triggered by a button click which is contained in the same `LabelFrame()` as suggested by the code snippet above (in the original code there are a lot more widgets but that's essentially the gist of my current problem).

Comment: There's nothing special you need to do that you don't do with any other type of python object. Tkinter doesn't have any special rules. The fact that the entry widget is in a labelframe is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @BryanOakley I would really appreciate it if you could be a little bit more explicit about what you are trying to imply because I spent more time trying to resolve this than I am willing to admit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `entry` to `self.entry`.

```
class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):

        ....
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self.groupbox)
        self.entry.insert(0, "default_value")
        self.entry.grid(row = 0, column=1)
        ...

    # Retrieve first Value (second Widget) from LabelFrame
    def compile(self):
        print(self.entry.get())
```